# Pytorch JIT Class

Tags: python, pytorch

Is every method of JIT Class complied? If so why JIT function is little faster than the class method? 
Please see the code below

```
import torch
import time

@torch.jit.script
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def calc(self, input: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return 1.0 / torch.exp(input)

@torch.jit.script
def calc(a):
  return 1.0 / torch.exp(a)

for i in range(5):
  test = Test()
  start = time.time()
  a = torch.zeros(6000, 200)
  for j in range(1000):
    a = test.calc(a)
  print(time.time() - start)

for i in range(5):
  start = time.time()
  a = torch.zeros(6000, 200)
  for j in range(1000):
    a = calc(a)
  print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Can you provide explicit timings that you are achieving in your runs?